# Problems to use GitHub api in backend with Axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to consume github's api in my express app, but its not working.
When i use my return with  res.json(console.log(users)), i recieve all users as i want, but when i use return res.json(users); sometimes i was recieving erro 500 and now this error:

```
Converting circular structure to JSON",
    "name": "TypeError"
```

I dont know why because this is a simple app..
here is my axios config:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
});

export default api;
```

here is my code with the methods:

```
class UserController {
  async show(req, res) {
    const { username } = req.query;

    if (!username) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid user' });
    }
    const user = await api.get(`/users/${username}`);

    return res.json(user);
  }

  async index(req, res) {
    const { page = 1 } = req.query;
    const users = await api.get(`users?since=${page}`);
    return res.json(users);
  }
}

export default new UserController();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios` returns a response object similar to the following:

```
data: {...}
status: 200
statusText: ""
headers: {..}
config: {...}
request: {...}
```

So ideally, I think you want to return `response.data`. So try

```
const response = await api.get(`/users/${username}`);
res.json(response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `data` property from the axios response, no?

```
const user = await api.get(`/users/${username}`);

return res.json(user.data);
```

See here: https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

The `request` field is a circular structure, so sending the entire response object will cause that error.